# Javascript is cached in development mode with asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I recently upgraded my application to rails 3.1 and generally everything seems to be working but one thing is driving me insane.

I have 2 main js files, we'll call them, application.js and main.js.

application.js has my manifest stuff in it and is loading in main.js. That's working fine. My problem is when i'm in development mode and i make a change to main.js, then refresh the page the site doesn't pick up the change. In order to pull in the change I have restart the rails server.

I have debug mode turned on in development, but I'm wondering if there's another setting i'm missing?

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: I have the same problem, hoping to find a solution here.  I can't seem to find any way to prevent from being served a cached JS file (or CSS for that matter).  Sux on those hard days when all you can do is change one tiny thing at a time, you hafta keep restarting the WEBrick over and over...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue, but `config.action_controller.perform_caching` was already set to false.

For me and another guy I was working with, the problem was that Chrome was caching the page despite the settings in Rails.

To fix it, we just closed the tab, opened a new tab, and visited the site again.

Comment: This ended up being it - the chrome thing actually. I still have no clue why but i had to actually manually clear browser cache and then it picked up the changes.

Comment: This just happened to me, restarting the browser seemed to fix this problem... it was as if it just suddenly decided to serve cached despite having perform_caching set to false. Strange.

Comment: Just spent the last 3 hours trying to solve this issue. I even restarted my computer, but since OSX now saves your open browser windows, apparently that didn't do it. Closed the tab, opened it, and problem solved. I think I'm gonna go shoot myself now.

Comment: Other solutions said run "rake assets:clean", but in reality the issue is chrome caching the js. Restarting browser works but it returns back to caching.

Comment: Yep, I think this was my problem too. I solved it by starting up the server in port 3001 and everything worked: `rails s -p 3011`. Tab thing is easier, though.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found that removing the asset digests in development fixed the issue. Make sure you set it to false in developmen.rb:

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I finally stumbled across something in my development.rb.  I had `config.action_controller.perform_caching` set to true, and changing it to false solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Opening Chrome in incognito mode worked best for me. No need to open and close a tab. In incognito mode, chrome doesn't cache javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that if you enable config.threadsafe, it will turn cache_classes on.  So if your config/environments/development.rb file contains the following:

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.threadsafe!
```

Then you are turning off cache_classes and then turning it right back on.  You will need to either comment out config.threadsafe (if you don't need it) like this:

```
config.cache_classes = false
# config.threadsafe!
```

Or, if you need threadsafe, reverse the order of these two configurations so that config_classes is really turned off:

```
config.threadsafe!
config.cache_classes = false
```

For more information, see http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your development log and see what it says when the application.js is served.

It should look something like this for a normal request (you browsed to a page):

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Sep 30 12:13:27 +1300 2011
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)
```

If not you may have not set the pipeline options correctly. One of the production settings might be in the wrong place. [Section 9](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails) of the asset pipeline guide has a checklist of correct settings for a migrated app.

Comment: yah i get Started GET "/assets/main.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-01 16:22:16 -0400
Served asset /main.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Comment: bah no line breaks in comments. seems like its serving from cache, ill look through the guide again

Comment: What headers do you see in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, config.action_controller.perform_caching set properly.  I also use Heroku and precompile assets for the Push to Heroku using: 
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
After the push, when I started new work, I forgot to remove the precompiled assets using:
sudo rm -r public/assets/*

So, no matter what I did to any of my .js files, they changes were not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

If above mentioned answers fail in your context..

make sure the caching is done by rails.. some times it does not detect changes in asset and serve the older cached version..

use 
`rails c` >> 
`Rails.cache.clear`
 or simply delete the caches in `tmp` dir

`[project_dir/tmp/cache/assets"]`

Answer (score 0):

We probably different root causes. But same symptom, and here's how I fixed my issue.

TLDR: If `[main-application-file]-[hash-id].js` is corrupt, then it won't update. So I had to do full removal of the `/public/assets` directory! Then did a rebuild of my app and restarted the rails server.

Details

The root cause for me was that my `application-[hash-id].js` was corrupted and wouldn't update! Even though when forced a rebuild I saw that `app/assets/builds/application.js` was picking up my changes. So I had to work backwards from the browser to see what files were being served from the `Rails server` and locate those. So when I saw the build code in `application.js` and public build code `application-[hash-id].js` were de-synced. I thought a good old deletion would do the trick!